Google Maps API Sending me old data
I made a little widget for a client that pulls place info from the google API by place ID and outputs it on their website so they only have to manage hours in their google profile. It connected, and everything was looking good, but now that they've made a change to their hours (closed wed and thurs this week), the edit is not coming through the API. Google is still sending me the old info.
I'm getting the weekday_text from the opening_hours...
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("hours-map"), {
    center: { lat: 29.9514775 , lng: -90.100022},
    zoom: 15,
  });
  const request = {
    placeId: "ChIJg3BoLpalIIYRToYZ5yCFQYI",
    fields: ["name", "formatted_address", "place_id", "geometry", "opening_hours"],
  };
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
    if (
      status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK &&
      place &&
      place.geometry &&
      place.geometry.location
    ) {
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
      });
const info = document.getElementById("hours-info");
var hours= place.opening_hours;
info.innerHTML = place.opening_hours.weekday_text[0]+ '<br>' +
         place.opening_hours.weekday_text[1] + '<br>' +
         place.opening_hours.weekday_text[2] + '<br>' +
         place.opening_hours.weekday_text[3] + '<br>' +
         place.opening_hours.weekday_text[4] + '<br>' +
         place.opening_hours.weekday_text[5] + '<br>' +
         place.opening_hours.weekday_text[6] + '<br>';
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
        const content = document.createElement("div");
        const nameElement = document.createElement("h2");

        nameElement.textContent = place.name;
        content.appendChild(nameElement);
        const placeAddressElement = document.createElement("p");

        placeAddressElement.textContent = place.formatted_address;
        content.appendChild(placeAddressElement);
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
  });
}


Maybe this will be helpful to others: I figured out that I was only pulling normal hours, and my client had updated their SPECIAL hours. Looks like I'll need a different API to get those... See Unable to get special opening hours from Google Places API

The issue is supposed to be fixed. The last comment says Please file new bugs if places are found to show secondary hours on Google Maps but not Places API (please include full Place Details API requests). - does your business show special hours on Google Maps website?
